# How to add a ScrollPane in a Panel

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jscrollpane

I'm trying to put a scrollbar in a JPanel.

I put my code on public static void main.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("Outil Replacement");
    frame.setSize(930, 610);
    frame.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(930,400));

    JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane();

    scrollPane.setWheelScrollingEnabled(true);

    frame.add(scrollPane);
    frame.setContentPane(new Replacement().panelMain);

    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.pack();
    frame.setVisible(true);
}
```

It does nothing.

Just a form view.

Is someone have a solution ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You rather set the target `JPanel` as the `JScrollPane`'s *viewport view* then add the `JScrollPane`, like this :

```
JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(new Replacement().panelMain);

scrollPane.setWheelScrollingEnabled(true);

frame.setContentPane(scrollPane);
```

See : [JScrollPane(java.awt.Component)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JScrollPane.html#JScrollPane(java.awt.Component))

And : [How to Use Scroll Panes](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/scrollpane.html)

Comment: That's that ! Thank you. Just for a little mistake.. A bad ".setcontent();"